# Insert to database Change the alias to a valid name?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a sql table which has an image cloumn I'm trying to insert the image after converting it into byte.... the my insert query looks like this

```
   INSERT INTO Member (F_NAME, L_NAME, D_O_B, UAE_ID_NO, MOBILE_NO, EMAIL_ID, REFERER, REF_CONTACT, ADDRESS, PICTURE) VALUES ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + dob.ToShortDateString() + "','" + uaeid + "','" + mobile + "','" + emailid + "','" + reffere + "','" + refercontact + "','"+address+"',"+photo+")"
```

here pic is the image column... I'm converting the image into byte array using the following method

```
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            //save the image into memory stream
            pBoxMember.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            //assign the byte array with total size of memorystream
            photo = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(photo, 0, photo.Length);
            return true;
```

But it is giving me this error
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
invalid syntax near ".

Comment: First thing to fix: your SQL injection vulnerability. *Don't* include values in SQL like this. Use parameterized SQL. It's unclear whether that will actually fix your current problem, but you *absolutely* should do it *immediately*. See [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

If this should work at all this should look like this:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO Member (F_NAME, L_NAME, D_O_B, UAE_ID_NO, MOBILE_NO, " + 
"EMAIL_ID, REFERER, REF_CONTACT, ADDRESS, PICTURE) " + 
"VALUES ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + dob.ToShortDateString() + "','" + uaeid + "','" + mobile + "','" + emailid + "','" + reffere + "','" + refercontact + "','" + address + "'," + photo + ")"
```

But you should use SQL Params for this, something like:

```
string queryString = "INSERT INTO Member (F_NAME, L_NAME, D_O_B, UAE_ID_NO, ... VALUES(@fname ,@lname ....)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, dbConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname",fname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname",lname);
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blobParam",YourBytesArray);
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```